# Register java based listeners in subwiki's for XWiki

Tags: java, components, listener, xwiki

We are working on a wiki farm containing various similar subwiki’s for various clients. The challenge I am really struggling with is, that I want to have different (java based) listeners registered for each subwiki. An example of such a listener is one that listens for save events to change the titel of the Wikipage. For this, I use model data stored in objects that might be different for each subwiki. In order to prevent having to reload these models every time the event is triggered, I want the model to be loaded once and re-use it. However, I have searched the last couple of days’s to find ways of defining / registering etc. listener components on a per-wiki basis but I can’t find what I am looking for.

Can someone help me understand how to build these listeners this way by (for example) directing me to an example?

Any help is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Is loading the model data that inefficient? Usually the hibernate cache present in XWiki should give this reasonable performance. (I do not know if registering listeners to subwikis is possible and I guess does not work, thus trying to work around the problem ... if performance is an issue, you could use a map wikiName -> data and store your data there.)

Comment: That is what we consider if we cannot register listeners on a subwiki basis. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your need, you might have at least 2 main solutions:

1. Use a single listener installed on the entire farm (either
   installed on the entire farm with the Extension Manager or just by
   dumping the jar in the "lib" folder) and keep a cache of your model,
   using the current wikiID as key. That way, when intercepting an
   event, your listener would get the current wiki ID (either from the
   context or from the affected document's reference) and use it to
   lookup the in-memory model, thus no longer requiring to initialize
   the model for each event. The cache can be anything from a simple
   map to a more configurable and scalable solution such as using
   XWiki's Cache Module.
2. Use the Wiki Component Manager and actually register N instances
   of your listener, one for each wiki. To do that, you could:

   1. [Deploy and use the Extension Manager UI to install](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/DevGuide/WritingComponents#HUsingtheExtensionManager) your component on each individual wikis (careful, not on the entire farm!). You
      could simplify this by making your component a dependency of the
      UI/flavor that you install on the subwiki, so that it will be
      installed automatically on the subwiki when you install the UI of
      that subwiki. This way, you component's code should only care about
      the current wiki (that it's installed on) and would only care about
      caching the model of the current wiki.
   2. Alternatively, a programmatic method would imply iterating over each existing wiki and, for each, setting the context wiki to the
      currently iterated wiki, dynamically getting the "wiki"
      ComponentManager (lookup "Namespaced Component Manager" in the "Component Module"'s documentation), creating a new instance of your listener and
      registering it to that wiki component manager. This code would run
      once, when the XWiki instance is started. However, you would then
      have to keep these component instances synchronized and, whenever a
      new wiki is created, you would have to register a new listener
      instance for it as well. There is no declarative way ATM that would
      simplify this process.

I don`t really recommend method 2.2 since, even if it might be possible, is unnecessarily complex.

Method 2.1 would be the simplest to write, but then needs a bit of work to deploy (i.e. your artefact needs to be available in a configured maven repo or in an XWiki Repository (also lookup the "XWiki Repository Application") so that the Extension Manager can install it).

Method 1 is both easy to implement and to deploy, so if that suits your usecase, I recommend it.

*Edit*: As noted in the comments, option 2 is not currently supported. See [XCOMMONS-213](http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XCOMMONS-213) for more details.

Comment: After 1, we moved to 2.1 since we like to stay close to XWiki system (we have our own repo running for this). However, when I install the listener on a second subwiki (after installation on a first subWiki), I get the message that is already installed under the same ID (SaveListener in this case). This made me consider using option 2.2. but I was not sure if this was a smart move since it looks quite complex indeed. I therefor guess that - according to your assessment - 2.1 is the best option. However: I don't know how to install the listener in a way that is only registered on the subwiki.

Comment: You are right, 2.1 is not currently supported. There is an already existing issue for it. Please refer to http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XCOMMONS-213

Basically, as a component, your listener is registered at a wiki level, but as a listener, it is registered at a root level, where `ObservationManager` lives, thus polluting the root level listeners.

You could try the workaround (using different/generated listener names) but I`m not sure it's worth it.

Comment: I currently register different listeners for each subwiki with a name based on the subwiki. This means that in a farm where X subwiki's live, there will be X listeners responding to a save (in my case). By checking the subwiki, I can filter the calls. As far as I can see, the document is actually saved only once (based on the version history). For now, this works for us: 4 listeners take the same millisecond to run and we do not expect to have 1.000 subwiki's running. I have to see what is workable especially since I have a delete listener with the same requirements.

Comment: Glad to hear you`ve come to an acceptable solution. Would you consider this question answered? If so, please mark it accordingly. Thanks!